# How to make query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

review table has store_idx, user_idx etc...

I want to create a query sentence that gets information about the store to which the user has bookmarked with the user_id value entered.

The query sentence I made is

```
select A.store_name
     , A.store_img
     , count(B.store_idx) as review_cnt 
  from board.store A 
  Left 
  Join board.review B 
    On A.store_idx is B.store_idx 
 where store_idx is (select A.store_idx from bookmark where user_id = ?)
```

However, nothing came out as a result.

Help me..

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data and desired result would helpful.

Comment: Obviously, the `where` clause is filtering out all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below Query:

```
SELECT store_name
     , store_img
     , SUM(review_cnt) AS review_cnt
  FROM
     ( SELECT DISTINCT A.store_name
            , A.store_img
           , CASE WHEN B.store_idx IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS review_cnt
       FROM bookmark br
       JOIN board.store A 
            ON A.store_idx = br.store_idx
       LEFT 
           JOIN board.review B 
             ON A.store_idx = B.store_idx 
    WHERE br.user_id = ?
     )T
```

Comment: You're missing a bit

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause is obviously filtering out all rows.  We can't do much about that.  But your query is also lacking a `GROUP BY`, the table aliases can be improved, and the `join` condition is not correct.

So, try this version:

```
select s.store_name, s.store_img, count(b.store_idx) as review_cnt 
from board.store s left join
     board.review r
     on s.store_idx = r.store_idx 
where b.store_idx in (select b.store_idx
                      from bookmark b
                      where b.user_id = ?
                     );
```